# Connect to Remotely Hosted WCF Service via netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, tcp, connect

I can connect to my WCF service locally with no problem but when I host it remotely, I receive this error:

TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.200.58:1991.

Please note that he firewall is already turned off on the host.

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: On the host machine, if your run netstat -o (command line) is your port shown correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a firewall problem. Check you port 1991 open on the target and client machines

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command (which requires elevated permissions - run as administrator)

```
netstat -anb
```

You have likely already searched but I found another question that might guide you to your answer;

[WCF No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980365/wcf-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused)